Matrix definiteness
Let $A$ be symmetrical $n\times n$ matrix with real coefficients. If all leading principal minors of matrix A are greater than 0 except very last one (the determinant of $A$ itself) which is equal to 0, can we say that $A$ is then positive semidefinite matrix, or should we check all principal minors? As far as I understood, it will be positive semidefinite if it has all eigenvalues non negative. Also if $x^TAx\geq 0$ for all non zero vectors $x$, but I am mostly interested in checking definiteness using minors. Thanks in advance. P.S. if we are using Hessian for determining if stationary point is extrema, and we got that Hessian at this point is indefinite, does this mean that function doesn't have extrema at this point or is the test inconclusive?

Second derivative test only provides sufficient conditions!

Due to symmetry and $\vert A\vert=0$, we can write $A$  as
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} M & M\ell \\ \ell^\top M & \ell^\top M\ell\end{bmatrix}
$$
for a symmetric positive definite $M$ and a vector $\ell$.
Thus, an arbitrary quadratic form $q$ can be written as
$$q=\begin{bmatrix}x^\top & y\end{bmatrix}A \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}
=x^\top M x +2 (\ell^\top M x)y + (\ell^\top M \ell)y^2. 
$$
This is a quadratic in scalar $y$. The discriminant is
$$\Delta=4(\ell^\top M x)^2 - 4 (\ell^\top M \ell)(x^\top M x)
=4\left( \left\langle x,\ell\right\rangle_M^2 -
\left\langle \ell,\ell\right\rangle_M \cdot
\left\langle x,x\right\rangle_M
\right) \leq 0
$$
by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. But the coefficient for $y^2$ is $ \ell^\top M \ell >0$ due to positive definiteness of $M$. So the quadratic form  $q\geq 0$, i.e., $A$ is nonnegative definite.

To answer your P.S. question:
No, if the Hessian is indefinite at a point you can't conclude anything.  Consider the examples
$f(x)=x^{4}$
$g(x)=-(x^{4})$
and
$h(x)=x^{3}$
at $x=0$.

A symmetric matrix is positive semidefinite if and only if all of its principal minors are nonnegative.
If a stationary point has indefinite Hessian, then it is a saddle point.
